# How can Vim help me remember the trailing commas in BibTeX files?

Tags: autocompletion

I edit quite a few BibTeX files, and I regularly forget the trailing commas:

For example:

```
@Book{cooke2015british,
 author = {Cooke, Lez},
 title = {British Television Drama},
 publisher = {Palgrave on behalf of the British Film Institute},
 year = {2015},
 keywords = {about}
 address = {London},
 isbn = {978-1844576234}
 }
```

You'll see that I forgot to add the comma after `keywords = {about}`, which will mean that I have to spend time debugging. Is there a way Vim can make me remember? By the way, I have the [bib_autocomp.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/bib_autocomp.vim/tree/master/ftplugin) plugin ...

Comment: Not that I know of, but you could try something like this to fix it: `:%s/[^ ,]\zs\ze\n\s*[^ }]/,/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quick and dirty solution:

```
:match Error /^\s\+.*,\@<!\ze\n\s\+\w/
```

You could also create a special syntax for BibTeX files using the same pattern.

Some explanations on the used regular expression:

1. `^\s\+` searches for indented keywords.
2. `\ze` stops the pattern matching such that the next line is not marked.
3. `,\@<!\n` searches for lines not ending with a comma.
4. `\n\s\+\w` guarantees that there is a new entry after the currently being scanned.

The same pattern can be used to jump between erroneous lines using `vimgrep` as following:

```
:vimgrep /^\s\+.*,\@<!\ze\n\s\+\w/ %
```

If the quickfix window does not open automatically, it can be opened using `:copen`. And `:cnext` and `:cprevious` can be used to jump between errors.

Comment: This is good! Can I somehow make it jump to the next error when I press n?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include what you asked for. See if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is defining a `.vimrc` shortcut to add the missing `,`

Example:

```
:map \q  :%s/\v([}"])(\s*\n\s*\S+\s*\=)/\1,\2/<CR>
```

and use `\q` before leaving or when debugging.

Comment: Not working for me? I get `E10: \ should be followed by /, ? or &                                                                                                      24,1 60%`, but perhaps I am doing it wrong?

Comment: @KristianNordestgaard, in `.vimrc`we have to remove initial ":" . Please try `map \q  :%s/\v([}"])(\s*\n\s*\S+\s*\=)/\1,\2/e<CR><CR>`